# Getting only 1st elements of list using sapply

Tags: r, arguments, sapply

I've read in R a data frame (df<-read.csv(data,as.is=T)) with n columns, one of which is a char column like this:

```
 df$qual
===========

1/5
12/17
...
0/3
9/14
```

I'd like to convert this column to a vector of numbers, keeping ONLY the 1st element of every row.

```
 df$qual
===========

1
12
...
0
9
```

I guess there's simpler ways (ideas welcome!), but I tried sapply:

```
sapply(df$qual,strsplit() ,simplify=T)
```

Now the problem is how/where I pass the argument split="/" so that this works? R help is not helping much.

thanks in advance,         p.

Comment: Strange thing to say to someone who has been using the site for almost a year :), but here it goes. You should probably take a look at the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see how the site works. In general when you think that an answer has solved your problem (and only then) it would be best if you could mark that answer as accepted so that other users can also benefit from it. You can accept an answer by clicking the green tick next to an answer. accepting an answer is not compulsory but it is encouraged when the answer solves the problem.

Comment: I am saying the above in a friendly way and by no means do I try to  offend you or tell you off :)

Comment: I would second @LyzandeR's comment -- 11 questions, 10 of them answered, with no answers accepted is considered a low acceptance ratio (you're not *required* to accept any answers, especially if you don't find them helpful, but it is considered good manners)

Comment: Just learnt that today. thnx for orientating.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps

```
sapply(strsplit(df$qual,split="/") , "[[", 1)
```

?

The explanation: `strsplit` generates a list of results, i.e. a character vector for each character element in the original input. The `"[["` is a short-hand way to call the indexing operator, and `1` says to pass the additional argument `1` to `[[` -- i.e., take the first element.  Two other, possibly more transparent ways to do the same thing:

```
sapply(strsplit(df$qual,split="/"), function(x) x[[1]])
```

or

```
sapply(strsplit(df$qual,split="/") , head, 1)
```

You may want to consider `as.numeric()` at the end.

Comment: Probably the best option anyway.

Answer (score 2):

A small alternative with an example (which I have been using so far):

```
myvec <- c('1/5', '12/17', '0/3','111/03') #define a vector

sapply(myvec, function(x) { #using sapply
  a <- gregexpr(pattern='/', x)[[1]][1]  #find location of '/'
  return(substring(x , 1, a-1)) #substring from start and up to 1 position before the '/'
} )
```

Output (you can `unname` that if you don't like names):

```
   1/5  12/17    0/3 111/03 
   "1"   "12"    "0"  "111"
```

Comment: Also works. I get this solution fine; my issue was mainly with passing arguments to sapply.

Answer (score 2):

There's a little bit of ambiguity between your title and description, so I'll share this anyway.

***Question 1***, on how to extract the first element of each list using `sapply` was adequately addressed by @BenBolker.

***Question 2***, on how to pass additional arguments to `sapply` seems to be unanswered. The answer to this is that you pass the additional arguments as the dots (`...`) arguments to `sapply`. For instance, you could have done:

```
sapply(yourvec, strsplit, "/", fixed = FALSE)
```

In the above, `"/"` and "`fixed = FALSE`" are being passed as additional arguments to `strsplit` in `sapply`. Note that this is a really inefficient approach since you are traversing the vector and splitting each individually while `strsplit` itself is already vectorized.

---

If your question is really about an efficient way to extract the first portion before a delimiter, I do have a couple of suggestions:

***Option 1***: Consider using `stringi`. Even splitting, converting to a matrix, and extracting the first column of the matrix is faster than the solutions I came up with in base R:

```
library(string1)
stri_split_fixed(myvec, "/", simplify = TRUE)[, 1]
```

***Option 2***: Consider using `sub` with a perl regular expression:

```
sub("(?=/).*", "\\2", myvec, perl = TRUE)
```

Option 3: Prefer `vapply` to `sapply`, and help `strsplit` out by adding `fixed = TRUE`:

```
vapply(strsplit(myvec, split = "/", TRUE), "[[", character(1L), 1)
```

---

If you want to compare the efficiency of each approach, try it out on a larger vector, like the one below:

```
myvec <- c('1/5', '12/17', '0/3','111/03')
myvec <- c(replicate(25000, myvec))
```

Comment: Such a good answer! My issue was with the arguments of sapply, clear now. I realised 'strsplit' is vectorised, so you can do this:
  strsplit(df$colname)
and it'd work. What I didn't know was how to keep only 1st element, and how to get rid of the 'list' inside the data frame.
  Re efficiency, your method is best.